# CakePHP - Get my application root address from model

Tags: cakephp

I am looking to get `http://www.mysite.com/app_directory` in the model.  Note my app is not in the site root.  I need it to perform a cURL request and I don't want to hard code it because the app location will change.  I also need the check to return `http://www.mysite.com` if the app moves to the site root.

About it being a bad idea to have the model know about its environment, I was wanting to check if a URl is an external web page or a URl within the current website.

Comment: Your model should not need to be aware of the environment it is in, this sounds like something your controller should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would do:

```
env('HTTP_HOST')
```

it's cake way of looking at:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```